# spring security HttpSession is null after Authentication success

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, httpsession

I am using spring security 3.0.5.RELEASE. After a successful authentication, user is not authenticated I have instead this messages in log

> 16/10/2014 00:08:17 [http-bio-8080-exec-5]
>   (AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:289) DEBUG -
>   Authentication success...
>
> 16/10/2014 00:08:17 [http-bio-8080-exec-5]
>   (HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:360) DEBUG -
>   SecurityContext stored to HttpSession:
>   'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@57920877:
>   ... 16/10/2014 00:08:17 [http-bio-8080-exec-5]
>   (SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:89) DEBUG -
>   SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed...
>
> 16/10/2014 00:08:18 [http-bio-8080-exec-6]
>   (HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:130) DEBUG - No HttpSession
>   currently exists 
>   16/10/2014 00:08:18 [http-bio-8080-exec-6]
>   (HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:88) DEBUG - No
>   SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one
>   will be created.

Here is my conf
web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

security.xml

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/denied.htm">
<security:intercept-url pattern="/"  access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/user/login"  access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**"  access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
<security:form-login    login-page="/user/login.htm"  authentication-failure-url="/user/login.htm?error=true"   default-target-url="/" />
<security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/index.htm" logout-url="/logout.htm" />
```

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- Use a Md5 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as Md5 in the 
    database -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder" />

<bean id="userDaoService" class="com.example.dao.jdbc.JdbcUserDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.cercle.core.services.impl.UserServiceImpl">
</bean>

<bean id="userDetails" class="com.example.model.User">
</bean>
```

Comment: But that's just a debugging message from Spring. Does it really break your business functionality?

Comment: user is not authenticated, in my JSP <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()"> return false.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Spring conf was OK, but my tomcat was running behind apache2 and I forgot to inform apache2 to conserve cookies (using command ProxyPassReverseCookiePath)